# Where to store the images of a custom WordPress theme?

Tags: php, images, localhost, local-installation

I am creating a custom theme. If I add a picture to the footer for example and the picture is in the folder of the theme, the picture does not display.

If I put it in the main wordpress folder it does display. What is the appropriate way to store all images from my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the path to the theme.

```
bloginfo('template_url');
get_bloginfo('template_url');
```

So:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/footer-image.jpg">
```